# waf - exit instantly from Task

Tags: python, waf

```
class superfoo(Task.Task):
     def run(self):
         self.generator.bld.fatal("Oh noes!")
```

**Is there any way to exit *without* printing a stack/backtrace?**

The above prints a stacktrace, a `return 1` does print some useless after task gibber.

Answer (score 2):

```
raise Errors.WafError('Test \'%s\' failed' % (testname))
```

is the best I could come up with.

```
Build failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/waf/.waf3-1.7.14-e013a2208e0c1f997a9c8d543692d171/waflib/Task.py", line 123, in process
    ret=self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/waf/.waf3-1.7.14-e013a2208e0c1f997a9c8d543692d171/waflib/Task.py", line 47, in run
    return m1(self)
  File ".wafcustom/unites.py", line 142, in run
    raise Errors.WafError('Test \'%s\' failed' % (testname))
waflib.Errors.WafError: Test 'microtests' failed
```